# Disable Update_Current_Timestamp MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query

```
`ALTER TABLE `user_account_keys` CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
```

It stops update_currnet_timestamp being enabled on a certain column. I need to disable it on every single column, in every single table, that comes under the type DateTime.

I'm not sure why MySQL has even enabled this without asking me.

Comment: You are about to alter the table forcing a column to be not null, so the client application suggests it to be filled with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. What other value should appear then?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is not the same data type as `DateTime` and the first timestamp you put on a table will have the default value of the current timestamp. You have to explicitly opt out to avoid this as this is the default behaviour. Just use an actual DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to another default value since the column in `NOT NULL`. You can either allow nulls and then remove the default value or set it to another default value.

```
`ALTER TABLE `user_account_keys` CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00'`
```

Change `'2000-01-01 00:00:00'` to whatever default value you need to use.

To change all the columns in the database, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('`ALTER TABLE `',TABLE_NAME,'` CHANGE `'
              ,COLUMN_NAME,'` `',COLUMN_NAME
              ,'` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '
              ,'2000-01-01 00:00:00','`' ) ALTERTABLE
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'timestamp';
```

This will give you a list of all the ALTER TABLE statements which you can verify before running using the EXEC command.

Comment: I want to do this for all tables, not just one.

Comment: This also only does it for 1 column, not every column under the 'datetime' type.

Comment: There is no generic script that you can run to change all columns through the database. You can write a query to generate it using the `information_schema` but you need to be careful before you execute it since it can do some damage.